# pydrive get only folders from list

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I use library [pydrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html) for google drive. Now I need get **all folders** (root, parent, child) name in google drive.
I have found this:

```
self.drive.ListFile().GetList()
```

but it returns all the files. Can I get only **all folders** in google drive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this modification? It retrieves the files with mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` using query.

- The mimeType of `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` means folders.
- `trashed=false` means that files are retrieved from outside of the trashbox.
- In this case, `title` means folder name.

#### Modified script :

```
f = self.drive.ListFile({"q": "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for folder in f:
    print(folder['title'])
```

#### References :

- [About `q`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.